# EJS rendering on page before for loop finishes/pushed to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, templating

I am attempting to render an array in HTML using EJS. But my EJS is rendering before the data is pushed to the empty array and therefore giving me an empty array rendered on the page.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', { testgroup: testgroup })
});

var testgroup = [];

for (var i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
    var test = problems[i].state;
    testgroup.push(test);
    console.log(testgroup)
}
```

What can I do to not render on the page until the for loop is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the loop inside the function where you render:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.get('/', function(req, res) 
    { 
        var testgroup = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i <  problems.length; i++){ 
             var test = problems[i].state;
             testgroup.push(test);
             console.log(testgroup) }
      res.render('index.ejs'{ testgroup:testgroup }) 
});
```

Comment: That's not what's reflected in your post. Post your actual code please.